# Aurelia custom element - $parent undefined

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-templating

I have template with repeater:

```
<template repeat.for="i of 2">
    <template repeat.for="j of 2">
        <p>${ $parent.$index } - ${ $index }</p>
    </template>
</template>
```

Which prints result:

```
0 - 0
0 - 1
1 - 0
1 - 1
```

If I use custom element `child-item` with the same template:

```
<template>
    <p>${ $parent.$index } - ${ $index }</p>
</template>
```

And write my original example using `child-item`:

```
<template repeat.for="i of 2">
    <child-item repeat.for="j of 2"></child-item>
</template>
```

Result is only:

```
-
-
-
-
```

Is there a way to propagate $parent and $index transparently to the `child-item`?

*UPDATE*

After trying few suggestions, closest I came is this:

```
<template repeat.for="i of 2">
    <child-item repeat.for="j of 2" parent-index.bind="$parent.$index" index.bind="$index"></child-item>
</template>
```

Where `child-item` template looks like:

```
<template bindable="parentIndex, index">
    <p>${ parentIndex } - ${ index }</p>
</template>
```

Binding `$parent` context directly with `parent.bind="$parent"` does not work. Parent index has to be bound directly. With this approach anything inline with `$parent.$parent.$index` is not achievable.

Answer (score 2):

something like this will work

child-item.ts:

```
import { customElement, bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

    @customElement('child-item')
    export class ChildItem {
      @bindable index;
    }
```

child-item.html

```
<template>
    <p>${ index }</p>
</template>
```

template with repeater:

```
<template>
    <require from="./child-item">

    <child-item repeat.for="child of childred" index.bind="$index"></child-item>
</template>
```

Comment: `$index` is passed to the custom element via `overrideContext` in `bind(bindingContext: Object, overrideContext: Object)`. So `$index` works by default and there is no need to bind it manually. Problem is how to make `$parent` available.

Comment: it's not clear from your code what you need `$parent` for? `bindingContext` is the parent though

Comment: I modified question to make it more clear and added update, after I tried your and @ashley-grant suggestions. I also had to bind index as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use databinding to pass it in. Add a `parent` or `index` bindable property to the `child-item` viewmodel.

Comment: Can you give a simple example? `index.bind="$index"` seems logical, but what should be value for current binding context? `parent.bind="..."`?